# Mesos Slave Failed to create a containerizer

Tags: docker, mesos, marathon

I want to Running Docker Containers on Marathon,

So I start the mesos-slave with  `--containerizers=docker,mesos`

```
  /usr/local/Cellar/mesos/0.22.1/sbin/mesos-slave --master=zk://localhost:2181/mesos --log_dir=/Users/wangyao/WorkAndLog/mesos/log --work_dir=/Users/wangyao/WorkAndLog/mesos/work --containerizers=docker,mesos
  I1216 11:17:16.407368 2038878976 logging.cpp:172] INFO level logging started!
  I1216 11:17:16.407878 2038878976 main.cpp:156] Build: 2015-05-12 19:28:23 by brew
  I1216 11:17:16.407896 2038878976 main.cpp:158] Version: 0.22.1
  Failed to create a containerizer: Could not create DockerContainerizer: Failed to execute 'docker version': exited with status 1
```

it told me "`Failed to execute 'docker version'`" ,

and I execute "`docker version`"

```
wangyaos-MacBook-Pro-2:~ wangyao$ docker version  
Client version: 1.7.0
Client API version: 1.19
Go version (client): go1.4.2
Git commit (client): 0baf609
OS/Arch (client): darwin/amd64
Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.19/version: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
```

My questions:

1. what is 'docker version' use for?
2. in order to start mesos with `--containerizers=docker,mesos`, do I need to install docker on my Os ?
3. how to solve this issue "Failed to execute '`docker version`'"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "[Running Docker Containers on Marathon](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/native-docker.html)" uses Docker, which means you need to have a Linux host.

If you are on Mac OS, you would need to install [docker-toolbox](https://www.docker.com/docker-toolbox) in order to get a VirtualBox VM (Virtual Machine) on which you can have docker.

[`docker version`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/version/) displays the version of the docker client *and docker server*: the server part fails, since it does not run on top of a Linux kernel (but a Mac one).

Comment: Thanks !  one more question,  i use the boot2docker on mac Os , so the boot2docker ip is '192.168.59.103' defaultlly ,  but when i start a docker containers on marathon,  marathon's healthey check will ask for "$my_host_IP : $port",  not  "$boot2docker_ip : $port" , absolutely, marathon could receive nothing from the url,  so the app's "healthey" status is UNHEALTHEY ,  how  could  i  solve it ?

Comment: @KingOfSocket make sure to use docker-machine. Once you are using docker 1.9, you can see of the issue persists, and ask a new question.